# Rellenar formulario dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy trabajando con un iframe y necesito forzadamente rellenar un formulario dentro de este y he intentado por bastantes días como poder realizar esto y no encuentro solución, me estoy volviendo loco, este es mi código:

HTML:

```
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="https://eboleta.sii.cl/" width="100%" height="700px" onload="func_frame1()"></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function func_frame1() {
                var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
                var oDoc1 = (frame1.contentWindow || frame1.contentDocument);
                if (oDoc1.document) oDoc1 = oDoc1.document;
                oDoc1.getElementById('input-14').value='123';
                oDoc1.getElementById('input-15').value='valor';
            }
```

Si alguien fuese tan amable de ayudarme se lo agradecería eternamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿No rellena el formulario? ¿Lo deja en blanco? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: Si, no me rellena el formulario, solo carga el iframe tal cual

Comment: No se puede acceder al iframe porque son dominios diferentes, no vas a tener permisos para entrar. No te sale un error de: "Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object"?

Comment: Si, creo que si me sale en la consola del crhome

Comment: No se podría descargar esta web para tratar de hacer ese proceso?, me funcionó con otra página pero el problema es que en esta página utilizan recursos de "Webpack" y no sé como llamarlos.